# Item name on side nav is also collapesed when closing nav bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I'm creating a side nav which can be opened and closed. The problem is the nav item's title is also collapsed when closing it and I want to fix this.

Like this

[image]

`css`

```
.sideNav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #263238;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sideNav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
```

`html`

```
<ul id="sideNav" class="sideNav nav flex-column" style="width: 250px;"><li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link>Title here</a></li></ul>
```

I change the width of the nav when opening and closing.

`js`

```
document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "250px"

document.getElementById('sideNav').style.width = "0"
```

Comment: You mean the "Title here" ? What exactly do you want when closing?

Comment: @ΑntonisPapadakis Yes "Title here" is collapsed when closing. What I want to do is to keep its layout when closing. It split into "Title" and "Here" when closing. Sorry I don't know how to describe well.

Comment: I think I understood..Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use negative `margin` equals to navbars width. When is closed it has negative margin and when is opened it has zero margin. For instance:

```
.sideNav {
   margin-left: -250px;
}
```

On opening

```
document.getElementById("sideNav").style.marginLeft = "0";
```

On closing

```
document.getElementById("sideNav").style.marginLeft = "-250px";
```